# Time/pitchshift in c

Tags: c, shift, pitch, rubber, pitch-shifting

I'm fairly new to C. As part of a Uni project, I'm required to put together a programme that processes audio in some form. So, I've decided to make a pitch shifter. So far, I've managed to at least make the program process the audiofile, if not actually alter the sound. I've looked into using samplerate, but from what I've gathered, it won't give me the desired outcome.

I've downloaded and compiled the rubberband library but I'm not really sure where to start using it in conjunction with my work. I was just wondering if anyone has any tips/experience with it, perhaps to achieve similar things?

```
void shiftsoundfile() {


    //Part 1 - File input and reading

        SNDFILE *inputsf, *outputsf;
        SF_INFO  ininfo, outinfo2;
        SRC_DATA src_data;

        static float datain [BUFFER_LEN];
        static float dataout [BUFFER_LEN]; 


        int readfile; 


            const char *inputsfname = "Scifi.wav";
            const char *outputsfname = "Scifi2.wav";


                ininfo.format = 0;
            if ( !(inputsf = sf_open(inputsfname, SFM_READ, &ininfo)))
                if (inputsf != inputsfname)
                {
                    printf("The file could not be opened.\n");
                    exit(0);
                }



            outputsf = sf_open (outputsfname, SFM_WRITE, &ininfo); 

            inputsf = sf_open (inputsfname, SFM_READ, &outinfo2);



            //Part 2 - Audio file conversion

            //>>SOMETHING NEEDS TO GO HERE TO PERFORM THE CONVERSION<<
                        //librubberband perhaps, or something along these lines?...

                            /*float shift [BUFFER_LEN];
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < readfile; j++) {
                 shift [j] = datain [j]; }

                for (j = 0; j < readfile; j++) {
                 datain [j] = shift [j]; }*/ //?


            //Part 3 - Outputting the new audio file

            while (readfile = sf_read_float (inputsf, datain, BUFFER_LEN)) 
            {


                sf_write_float (outputsf, datain, BUFFER_LEN);
                //Write's the data in the array, pointed to by outputsf, to the file
            }




            sf_close (inputsf); //closes the 'osf' function
            sf_close (outputsf); //closes the 'csf' function
```

Comment: You're right, sample rate doesn't affect what you want it to, it has more to do with sound quality, with, just FYI, higher sample rates generally corresponding with better audio.

Comment: What concerns the audio part of the question, http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ could be a better place to ask... If it's just about the implementation, it would probably be good to provide more specific input (e.g. part of your code) and questions.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some of the code I've got so far. I've stripped out my original formatting as it was just converting my soundfile  incorrectly. I guess I just need a starting point for effectively 'pitch shifting' ?